# Generating consecutive numbers from matrix multiplication.

Tags: matrices

I'm new to matrix multiplication and was trying to generate a sequence of consecutive numbers from the product of two $2 \times 2$ matrices and noticed this pattern. Let

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} n & n+1 \\ n+2 & n-1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} m & m-1 \\ m-1 & m \end{pmatrix},  \quad C = AB
$$

Compute

\begin{align*}
C &= \begin{pmatrix} n & n+1 \\ n+2 & n-1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} m & m-1 \\ m-1 & m \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} nm + (n+1)(m-1) & n(m-1) + (n+1)m \\ (n+2)m + (n-1)(m-1) & (n+2)(m-1) + (n-1)m \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 2nm - n + m - 1 & 2nm + m - n \\ 2nm + m - n + 1 & 2nm + m - n - 2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Let $k = 2nm + m - n$, then

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix} k - 1 & k \\ k + 1 & k - 2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

which yields consecutive numbers $k-2,k-1,k,k+1$.

## Example

Let $n=150, m=16$. Then multiplying

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
150 & 151 \\
152 & 149 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
16 & 15 \\
15 & 16 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
4665 & 4666 \\
4667 & 4664 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

gives $k=4666$ with consecutive numbers $4664, 4665, 4666, 4667$.
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B150%2C%20151%7D%2C%20%7B152%2C%20149%7D%7D%20.%20%7B%7B16%2C%2015%7D%2C%20%7B15%2C%2016%7D%7D)

## Questions

Can that method be generalized to two $n \times n$ matrix products, resulting in $n^2$ consecutive numbers?

Aside, is there a way to ensure the $n^2$ consecutive numbers are always composite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works because
$$\eqalign{A &= n \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr} + \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 2 & -1\cr}\cr
B &= m \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr} + \pmatrix{0 & -1\cr -1 & 0\cr}}$$
and $$ \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 2 & -1\cr} \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr} = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr}$$
(because both row sums of $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 2 & -1\cr}$ are $1$), while
$$ \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr} \pmatrix{0 & -1\cr -1 & 0\cr} = \pmatrix{-1 & -1\cr -1 & -1\cr}$$ (because both column sums of $\pmatrix{-1 & 0\cr 0 & -1\cr}$ are $1$),
$$\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 2 & -1\cr} \pmatrix{0 & -1\cr -1 & 0\cr} = \pmatrix{-1 & 0\cr 1 & -2\cr} $$
and
$$\pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr} \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr}  = \pmatrix{2 & 2\cr 2 & 2\cr} $$
so $$A B = (n m - n + 2) \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr} + \pmatrix{-1 & 0\cr 1 & -2\cr}$$
has its entries four consecutive integers.

For a similar pattern in $n \times n$ matrices, let $E$ be the $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are all $1$.  We want $F$ be an $n \times n$ matrix whose
entries are $n^2$ consecutive integers, with all row sums equal.  Note that
the sum of $n^2$ consecutive integers starting with $a$ is $S(a,n) = ((n^2 + a)^2 - n^2 - a^2)/2$. The row sums would have to be $S(a,n)/n = (n^3 - n)/2 + a n$.  Since $n^3 - n$ is always even, that is always an integer. For example,
for $n = 5$ one possibility is
$$ F = \pmatrix{14 & 16 & 13 & 10 & 12\cr 11 & 7 & 22 & 19 & 6\cr 
18 & 17 & 21 &  4 & 5\cr 20 &  9 & 25 &  8 & 3\cr  23 & 24 & 15 &  2 & 1\cr}$$
And let $G$ be a permutation matrix.  Then $A = x E + F$, $B = y E - G$ will work.